# Routing static content in VertX

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I'm using Vert.X (*via the org.jetbrains.kotlinx:vertx3-lang-kotlin library*) with Kotlin and I'm trying to build a single-page application that is self-contained in a jar.

On the maven side, these are my dependencies:

```
<properties>        
    ...               
    <vertx.version>3.3.2</vertx.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.0.3</kotlin.version>
    <main.class>Bob</main.class>
</properties>
```

```
<!-- Vertx Dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    <version>${vertx.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    <version>${vertx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Kotlin Dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Kotlin Vertx Binding Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx3-lang-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>[0.0.4,0.1.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

In my main class, I've got the following:

```
object Bob {

    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
    val port = 9999

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

       DefaultVertx {
            httpServer(port = Bob.port, block = Route {
                GET("/") { request ->
                    headers().add("Author", "Re@PeR")
                    contentType("text/html")
                    sendFile("html/index.html")
                }
                otherwise {
                    setStatus(404, "Resource not found")
                    body {
                        write("The requested resource was not found\n")
                    }
                }
            });
       }


    }
```

Going to `localhost:9999` the index.html is serving successfully.
I now want to be able to request css / js files and serve them as well

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For each of the resources, the browser returns an error 404 as expected.

I'm now trying to serve the CSS using

```
             GET("/css/*") {
                request ->
                    println("Serving CSS")
                    contentType("text/css")
                    sendFile("css/${request.path()}")
            }
```

But I'm not seeing it ever entering that block and it continues to serve error 404s.

What is the correct way to serve static files in Vert.X using *org.jetbrains.kotlinx:vertx3-lang-kotlin* library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler.
In your example it could be:

```
router.route("/css/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());
```

But actually, you should put everything under /static or /public folder and server it like that:

```
router.route("/static/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());
```

It my Kotlin applications it usually looks like:

```
val router = Router.router(vertx)

router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create())
// Other routes here...
```

When you create StaticHandler that way, it will server from `/resources/webroot` directory by default.

Comment: Where do I call `router.route`, inside `Route { ... }` ? I'll try it first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: I added a full example in Kotlin in my original answer. Enjoy!